# autoupdater для игры

Tags: gui, c++

Существует некий игровой проект, имеется мощный фтп узел. Пришла в голову идея создать автоапдейтер для игры (такой например как апдейтер линейдж 2, танки онлайн). Нормального мануала в интернете я не нашел. Прошу помощи в этом деле. (дайте ссылку на мануал, либо опишите как чего)

З.Ы. По моим соображениям программу надо писать на с++, но нет времени на обучение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сервер каким либо образом отдает программе информацию о текущей версии (файл, овтет на запрос, не важно). Программа парсит файлтекст. Версию в нём сравнивает со своей, если отличается в большую сторону, берёт ссылку (тут принцип тоже не важен, спец. сформированная строка в которую тупо подставляется версия, либо же в том же файле) получает файл по ссылке, заносит его в свою директорию, заменяет текущие и перезапускается. Последние пункты можно выполнить с помощью демона

Comment: это я все понимаю, мне нужен сам код программы (или пример таких действий в среде C++).

Comment: Вам нужен? Ну в таком случае идите учите С и пишите. Будут вопросы с написаной программой обращайтесь. Не хотите учить - вам во фриланс, а не сюда

Comment: вот именно :P

Comment: Во фриланс мне точно не надо, в вопросе стоит намек на мануал (полное описание данных действий), сожалею, но ответа не проследовало.

Comment: Я в ответе вам полностью все написал, все действия. В чем проблема?